# Jenkins Packages on Groovy Classpath?

Tags: java, groovy, hudson, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When using the Groovy Jenkins plugin (not the Groovy Post Build Plugin, which is a different thing) as a Post Step, I can't resolve classes in the `hudson.model` package.

Do I need to add the Jenkins .war onto the classpath, or should these packages already be there?

**Script:**

```
import hudson.model.*;
import hudson.util.*;

AbstractBuild currentBuild = (AbstractBuild) Thread.currentThread().executable;
def mavenVer = currentBuild.getMavenArtifacts().getModuleRecords()[0].mainArtifact.version;
println mavenVer;
ParametersAction newParamAction = new hudson.model.ParametersAction(new hudson.model.StringParameterValue(“MAVEN_VERSION”, mavenVer));
currentBuild.addAction(newParamAction);
```

**Output:**

```
[Common] $ /home/tester/tools/Groovy_1.8.3/bin/groovy /home/tester/workspace/Common/hudson8369102960709507246.groovy
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/tester/workspace/Common/hudson8369102960709507246.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class AbstractBuild 
 @ line 8, column 15.
   AbstractBuild currentBuild = (AbstractBuild) Thread.currentThread().executable;
[...]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if it's a `Groovy Script` you *do* need to add the `jenkins-core` jar to your classpath, and the stapler jar too.

If it's a `Groovy System Script` then it is run inside the master's JVM, meaning all the Jenkins classes and dependencies are already on the classpath.

Comment: Is it really possible to run your code above as a simple `Groovy Script` when adding the correct jar to the classpath?  From the Groovy plugin documentation I have the impression that the code will not work as it is in a different JVM instance, so you'll not be able to add a parameter in the already running JVM.

Comment: @engineerbetter I know this is old, but care to share how these jars get put in the classpath in regards to Jenkins and Groovy? Do I simply go in the advanced configuration of my Groovy script, specify the classpath where my jars are hosted?